# Removing calendar events created by delegate user in Exchange 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, powershell, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

In Exchange 2010, is it possible to remove calendar events created by a specific delegate user? I don't want to remove events that were actually created by the mailbox owner.

Answer (score 0):

On the recipient side, we can look for "X-MS-Exchange-Inbox-Rules-Loop" in the header information which could identify that the invitation was sent by a delegate. However, I am not aware of a way to filter out the events from the organizer side.

Comment: Is it possible to get the value of the `X-MS-Exchange-Inbox-Rules-Loop` property using a PowerShell/Exchange Management Shell cmdlet? If so, could you please give me an example?